# Web Crawler - Ignore Robots.txt file?

Tags: python, web-crawler, mechanize, robots.txt

Some servers have a robots.txt file in order to stop web crawlers from crawling through their websites. Is there a way to make a web crawler ignore the robots.txt file? I am using Mechanize for python.

Comment: If you do this, there are presumably legal issues

Comment: Downvoting this is bad since it is a legit question. However this is a bad idea.

Comment: [An interesting alternative view on ignoring robots.txt](http://www.archiveteam.org/index.php?title=Robots.txt)

Comment: While I agree ignoring robots.txt is a bad idea what do you propose are the legal issues?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [documentation](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) for mechanize has this sample code:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
....
# Ignore robots.txt.  Do not do this without thought and consideration.
br.set_handle_robots(False)
```

That does exactly what you want.

Comment: I suggest raising your issue on [flagging this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373398/creating-replacement-tapplication-for-experimentation) on meta yet again. There seems to be different opinions on how suspected copyright violations should be handled, and a definitive answer would help.

Comment: @NullUser will do. I'll try and collect together in one place all the conflicting advice I have had, and see if we can't all come to a common viewpoint!

Answer (score 9):

[**This**](http://dinomite.net/2007/web-browsing-with-python/) looks like what you need:

```
from mechanize import Browser
br = Browser()

# Ignore robots.txt
br.set_handle_robots( False )
```

but you know what you're doing…