# Way around HTTP 403 with python

Tags: python, http, error-handling, mechanize, http-status-code-403

im makeing a program that uses google to search but i cant becuase of the HTTP error 403 is there any way around it or anything im using mechanize to browse here is my code

```
from mechanize import Browser

inp = raw_input("Enter Word: ")
Word = inp

SEARCH_PAGE = "https://www.google.com/"

browser = Browser()
browser.open( SEARCH_PAGE )
browser.select_form( nr=0 )

browser['q'] = Word
browser.submit()
```

here is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Project\Auth2.py", line 16, in <module>
browser.submit()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 541, in submit
return self.open(self.click(*args, **kwds))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 255, in _mech_open
raise response
httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: request disallowed by robots.txt
```

please help and thank you

Comment: You're going to end up getting banned temporarily by google if you do this too many times.  Using Google search programmatically is a pay for service provided by Custom search API ( 100 free queries per day for development)

Comment: This problem look awefully similar to [urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden/46213623#46213623)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can tell Mechanize to ignore the `robots.txt` file:

```
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
```

Comment: now im getting this    httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: @ChristianCareaga: You have to change your user agent: https://views.scraperwiki.com/run/python_mechanize_cheat_sheet/?

Answer (score 2):

Mechanize tries to respect crawling limitations announced by the `/robots.txt` file on the site.Here, Google does not want crawlers to index its search pages.

You can ignore this limitation:

```
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
```

as stated in [Web Crawler - Ignore Robots.txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386481/web-crawler-ignore-robots-txt-file)

Also, I would recommend using [Google's Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest) instead, which exposes a proper API with easily parseable results.