# Ignoring robots.txt and meta tags in a crawler

Tags: robots.txt

Are there a way to make a web crawler ignore the robots.txt file and  tags? Yes, I know this could come with legal repercussions. This question is much like [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386481/web-crawler-ignore-robots-txt-file) but the answers were very vague and I didn't quite get it. any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

A web crawler doesn't have to adide by a robots.txt, because there is no physical measure in place to stop it if it doesn't do so.

A simple webcrawler might do:

```
FOR SITE IN SEARCH
    IF ALLOWED_TO_CRAWL_BASED_ON_ROBOTS_TXT(SITE)
        FOR LINK IN SITE
             DO_SOMETHING
```

this could be modified to:

```
FOR SITE IN SEARCH
    FOR LINK IN SITE
       DO_SOMETHING
```