# Overriding "Vcl.Forms.Application: TApplication"

Tags: delphi

I want to extend TApplication by adding extra methods, variables, and code to be initialized in the constructor.
Deriving my own class from TApplication won't work, obviously, because the global VAR Application is declared (Vcl.Forms) and instantiated  (VclControls.InitControls) as TApplication.  Obviously, I will try to stay away from hacking and recompiling that unit.

There is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373398/creating-replacement-tapplication-for-experimentation) on SO that might seem similar, but it is not because the owner of the post wants to override the TApplication for a whole different reason.

---

The class declaration would be something like (work in progress):

```
TYPE
  TAppData= class(TObject)
  private
    FAppName: string;
    FLastFolder: string;        { used by AppLastUsedFolder }    //todo: reaname to FLastFolder
    function getLastUsedFolder: string;

   public
    Initializing: Boolean;        { Used in cvIniFile.pas. Set it to false once your app finished initializing. }

    constructor Create(aAppName: string);

   {--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      App path/name
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
    function  AppDir    : string;
    function  SysDir : string;

    function  AppDataFolder(ForceDir: Boolean= FALSE): string;
    function  AppDataFolderAllUsers: string;

    function  AppShortName: string;

    property AppName: string read FAppName;
    property LastUsedFolder: string read getLastUsedFolder write FLastFolder;

   {--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      App Control
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
    function  RunningFirstTime: Boolean;
    procedure Restart;
    procedure SelfDelete;
    procedure Restore;
    function  RunSelfAtWinStartUp(Active: Boolean): Boolean;
    function  RunFileAtWinStartUp(FilePath: string; Active: Boolean): Boolean;                             { Porneste anApp odata cu windows-ul }

    {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      APPLICATION Version
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
    function  GetVersionInfoV      : string;                            { MAIN. Returns version without Build number. Example: v1.0.0 }
    function  GetVersionInfo(ShowBuildNo: Boolean= False): string;
    function  GetVersionInfoMajor: Word;
    function  GetVersionInfoMinor: Word;
    function  GetVersionInfo_: string;

    function  getVersionFixedInfo(CONST FileName: string; VAR FixedInfo: TVSFixedFileInfo): Boolean;

   {--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      BetaTester tools
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
    function  RunningHome: Boolean;
    function  BetaTesterMode: Boolean;
    function  IsHardCodedExp(Year, Month, Day: word): Boolean;
  end;
```

---

I thought of a Class Helper but I need to initialize stuff in the constructor:

```
constructor TAppData.Create(aAppName: string);
begin
  inherited Create;
  Initializing:= True;                            { Used in cvIniFile.pas. Set it to false once your app finished initializing. }
  FAppName:= aAppName;
  FRunningFirstTime:= NOT FileExists(IniFile);
  ForceDirectories(AppDataFolder);

  //ToDo: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! CreateLogForm; But this will create dependencies on the Log!
end;
```

Comment: "Obviously, I will try to stay away from hacking and recompiling that unit." Why? The simple method that works.

Comment: 1. You can break stuff there if the unit is not recompiled properly (for example, all compiler directives need to be properly set). 2. The hack resets every time you reinstall Delphi, every time you update Delphi. 3. You need to port the hack to new versions of Delphi.  4. You cannot actually distribute the code to others (not without lots of instructions on how to apply the hack). So imply put, a hack is a hack. BUT I said I will "try to stay away". If my solution is hackyer than this, then I will prefer the less hackyer.

Comment: Could you just use a class helper and some global variables for the state?

Comment: That was my idea also, but I need to initialize stuff in the constructor. I just posted the code in the constructor. The variables were already global, I just moved them in a class (today) :)

Comment: If you don't need to change behavior of Application instance, then you don't need to "override" anything. Just create your own singleton class - like you have and use it. Right now there is no question in your question as there is no problem presented.

Comment: I agree with Dalija Prasnikar.  Based on what you have shown so far this could be all simply put into a separate class which you then initialize by calling its constructor inside your project file just before calling `Application.Run`.